# How to make sure that a function returns after an async block has been executed?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm working with Angular 4.2.4 / RxJS 5.4.2, and I'm trying to use a service method to retrieve some data and assign that data to a property in my component:

***component:***

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.componentProperty = this.myService.serviceMethod(someParameter);
}
```

***service:***

```
serviceMethod(someParameter: someType) {

    let returnValue: anotherType;

    // getting the Observable involves using "someParameter"
    // (the code was simplified for the sake of clarity)
    someObservable.subscribe(
        data => { returnValue = data; }
    );

    return returnValue;    
}
```

The problem is that the function inside `subscribe()` gets executed asynchronously, thus the method always returns `undefined`.

Any thoughts on how to solve this? A special RxJS method? Some fancy ES.next keyword I'm not aware of? Another logical design (that keeps the SoC neat and clean)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services methods should generally *return* values that are `Observable`s or `Promise`s.

In the case of `Observable`s you would write something like

```
serviceMethod(someParameter: someType) {
  return getSomeObservable(someParameter);
}
```

in your service and something like

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.serviceMethod(someParameter).subscribe(value => {
    this.componentProperty = value;
  });
}
```

to consume it in your component.

Answer (score 1):

Just chain it. A simple way:

```
return someObservable.subscribe(
        data => { call the function you want }
    );
```